# OAuth Header WSDL Web service

Tags: c#, spring, oauth, wsdl

I have created the following: Spring, Spring OAuth, Enunciate api with WSDL, C# OAuth test and C# WSDL web service test. Everything is working perfectly after some hefty reading.

I have now enabled Spring OAuth for the /soap/xxxservice therefore I get an errors on the WSDL webservice as OAuth redirects to a HTML login page (missing the Authorization header). 
Note that the code is auto generated by importing the WSDL WebSerice into VS2010.

To solve this I need to insert an HttpWebRequest header called "Authorization".

I can get this to work by manually coding the HttpWebRequest but then there are no pritty methods or objects... plain Requests and XML responses ... eeewwww

Is there a way of combining WSDL auto generated code and a custom http.header to support OAuth 1.0a?

ta in advance